# NSMutableArray addObject mistake

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I can not addObject into 'easyQArray' (NSMutableArray). It did work when I had the array defined locally but when I moved the declaration into the .h file it does not work anymore.

The app crash ofc as I try to access an index in the array that does not exist:

```
// Create question arrays
if (easyPlayers > 0) {
    for (int XX = 0; XX < easyQuestions; XX++) {
        [easyQArray addObject: [myArray objectAtIndex: easyQStartPos]];
        NSLog(@"myArray: %@", [myArray objectAtIndex: easyQStartPos]);
        NSLog(@"easyQArray: %@", easyQArray);
        easyQStartPos = easyQStartPos + 1;
    }
}
```

Output:

> 2010-12-28 15:52:57.636 XX_v2[11582:207] myArray: 205
>   2010-12-28 15:52:57.636 XX_v2[11582:207] easyQArray: (null)
>   2010-12-28 15:52:57.636 XX_v2[11582:207] myArray: 71
>   2010-12-28 15:52:57.637 XX_v2[11582:207] easyQArray: (null)
>   2010-12-28 15:52:57.637 XX_v2[11582:207] myArray: 94
>   2010-12-28 15:52:57.638 XX_v2[11582:207] easyQArray: (null)
>   2010-12-28 15:52:57.638 XX_v2[11582:207] myArray: 133
>   2010-12-28 15:52:57.638 XX_v2[11582:207] easyQArray: (null)
>   2010-12-28 15:52:57.639 XX_v2[11582:207] myArray: 142
>   2010-12-28 15:52:57.640 XX_v2[11582:207] easyQArray: (null)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems that you didn't even init your Array. From your description it sounds like your declared it as a property so calling alloc / init in your class init method should fix your problem.

```
easyQArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: Also don't forget to release this in dealloc.

Answer (score 0):

easyQArray is defined but where is it allocated? (my guess is that it isn't as your log shows that it's nil)

The likely missing line:

```
easyQArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work even if you moved it .h.
Make sure you initialize your `easyQArray`. And make  sure you initialized it as `NSMutableArray`.
Initialization should take place before you do the `addObject` in `[easyQArray addObject: [myArray objectAtIndex: easyQStartPos]];`